# ESP32 Potentiometer issue: Resolution mismatch of the potentiometer with unlimited resolution and reading the values with Wire.h

Tags: esp32, adc, potentiometer

I have the problem, that the potentiometer goes from the range of 0 Volts to 3,3 volts. But within this range the measured value goes **from about 0 to 65535 multiple times** (over 10 cycles).

When I change the code from my ADC library to 32 bit I get 32 bit values (0 - 4294967296) but the same error with the beginning at 0 multiple times within the potentiometer range occurs.

**Hardware:**

**Board:** ESP32
**ADC:** MAX11613 (12 bit adc)
https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/256/MAX11612-MAX11617-1508955.pdf
**Potentiometer:** 3046L - 3 - 203 https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/54/3046-776396.pdf

Part of the code that reads the adc values:

```
uint8_t MAX11613::MAX11613_ADC_Read(structMAX11613* chip, uint8_t channel, uint16_t* val){
    
    uint8_t configurationByte = ( (channel<<1) & 0x0e) | 0x61;
    MAX11613_Configuration(chip, configurationByte);

    Wire.beginTransmission(chip->devAddress);
    Wire.requestFrom(chip->devAddress, (byte) 2);    // request 2 bytes from slave device wireIface
    while (Wire.available()) { // slave may send less than requested
    //char c = Wire.read(); // receive a byte as character
    
    uint16_t value = 0;
    value =  Wire.read();
    value |= Wire.read() << 8;

    //This also works:
    /*uint32_t buf1;
    size_t actually_read = Wire.readBytes((uint8_t*)&buf1, 2);
    *val = actually_read;
    //Serial.println(value);*/

    *val = value;
    }
    if (Wire.endTransmission() != 0){
    return 1;
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX1161x are 12-bit ADCs, so the problem is not related to an uint16 overflow as you seem to assume.
The ADC transmits most significant bits (MSB) first as can be seen [in figure 10 on page 17](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/256/MAX11612-MAX11617-1508955.pdf). To account for that you need to change

```
value =  Wire.read();
value |= Wire.read() << 8;
```

to

```
value = Wire.read() << 8;
value |=  Wire.read();
```

Comment: Youre absolutely right. In addition I had to edit the first byte transmitted, because it only transfers the first 4 digits (4 bits + 8 bits = 12 bits):

Comment: value = (Wire.read() & 0x000f) << 8;
 value |=  (Wire.read() & 0x00ff);